# Nodejs - npm start & npm build both do not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

this is a snippet from my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "mkdir BigDirectory",
    "build": "mkdir BigDirectory"
  },
```

I've noticed that `npm build` simply goes to the next new line in terminal (without creating a directory)

While `npm start` works and creates the "BigDirectory"

Why is `npm build` non-responsive? Am i perhaps allowed only one single script in my package.json?

Comment: use `npm run build`. start is exclusive case where you don't need to type `run`

Comment: @zaynetro besides `start` there's also `restart`, `stop` and `test`.

Comment: @robertklep, thanks! somehow completely forgot others